# How to Add Owl carousel slider to homepage in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, slider

I have a issue related to owl slider
I make a slider into phtml file slider.php
And call into default.xml file.but the problem it is not take a slider to homepage..
Thanks

Comment: What you have passed in your default.xml file ?

Comment: I want in block then what am i doing?

Answer (score 0):

> **IF you want that in your block , Then call your slider block name and your template name to homepage cms block.**

**Try below code :**

```
{{block class="VendorName\Modulename\Block\Blockname" template="Vendorname_ModuleName::your_template_file.phtml"}}
```

> You can find your homepage block from **admin
>   ->content->Blocks->Homepage Block** . Edit it and call your block by written above code.

Comment: Hello Manthan..!! create a one block and in that call images then in phtml file call js and css for the slider..is is proper?

Comment: @MoinMalek yes call your css in layout file and js in requirejs-config.js and pass it to your template file . it will works

Comment: You can create a widget to be used in different area and you can configure it through backoffice.

Comment: can u send a structure